# vuforia unity project on android phone shows triangle broken screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I currently have a simple Vuforia and Unity project for android where I have a postcard as a target, and then you can cycle through a set of pictures while you are looking at the target by swiping left and right on the screen. However when I run the demo on my android phone(Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge), the demo divides the screen into two separate triangles where one is completely black, and the other triangle changes color based on where the camera for the phone is facing. I've attached a still image of the problem where it shows white for one triangle, black for the other, and my image target is the postcard placed on the table [broken demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0J4S.jpg).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this error has been going on for some time. If I need to post anything else please feel free to let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we faced this problem too. Here is the solution-

Go to Build Settings > player Settings , On the right hand side a window will change, go to Other Settings and Auto Graphics API untick, and Open GLES3 remove it by pressing negative sign

Hope it works

Comment: Yup that was it! Works perfectly now. Thanks a bunch for the help!